# how to Trigger a method in Grand-Parent class from child

Tags: c#, winforms

I've a scenario to inform user in a `winform` about the date he selected in another `winform`. I framed that in `class` structure. Tried to use `events` by subscribing the method in my `Foo` and planning to trigger from `Roo`

But I can't achieve that unless I create another session of `Foo` in `Roo` which won't work the way I wanted

```
class Foo
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Too to = new Too();
        //
        Foo fo = new Foo();
        fo.PromptUser();
    }

    void PromptUser()
    {
        // If date is in Past
            //some logic
        // If future
            // some logic
    }
}

class Too
{
    public void Too_Method()
    {
        Roo ro = new Roo();
    }
}

class Roo
{
    //In this class, User will be able to
    // Select a date
}
```

How to pass/know the date selected in `Roo` class to define the logic in my `Foo` class??

Comment: And I shouldn't call `Foo` from `Roo`

Answer (score 0):

Use static method so no need to instantiate the class

```
class Roo
{
  public static dateTime selectedDate()
   {
    //selected date
    return //selected date
   }
}
```

In Foo class call the static method by ClassName.staticmethod directly

```
class Foo
 {
   dateTime userSelectedDate = Roo.selectedDate();
 }
```

OR another way is use inheritance,

```
  class Foo : Roo
  {

  }
```

Comment: I can't call `Roo` from my `Foo` class and shouldn't inherit as well

Comment: change your Roo class to a static class and declare the variable as static so that it can be accessed across all forms.

Comment: Sorry mate. Our architecture won't allow such change and at the same time class `Roo` is used by many other classes. I can't convert any of these class designs for this requirement

Comment: Can you modify the existing Roo class, annotate / add static method for setting the selected date?